# Casting arrays and structs

Tags: c, sockets, casting

Suppose I have some complex struct

```
struct icmphdr
{
     u_int8_t type;
     u_int8_t code;
     u_int16_t checksum;

    /* Parts of the packet below don’t have to appear */
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            u_int16_t id;
            u_int16_t sequence;

            // Type of ICMP message
            // Packet code
           // Datagram checksum
        } echo;

        u_int32_t gateway;

        struct
        {
            u_int16_t __unused;
            u_int16_t mtu;
        } frag;


   } un;

};
```

and a

```
char buf[SIZE];//for some integer SIZE
```

what is the meaning and the interest of this cast ?

```
ip=(struct icmphdr*)buf; //ip was formerly defined as some struct iphdr *ip;
```

Comment: what is iphdr ot it's a typo mistake which should be icmphdr???

Comment: @Dayalrai sorry, yes it is a typo

Comment: You are basically stuffing whatever is in `buf` into that `struct`.. whether it is valid or not is another issue.

Answer (score 1):

The likely scenario behind your code is this:

The programmer wanted to create a data protocol and represent the various contents as a struct, to ease programming and improve code readability.

The underlying API probably only allows data transmissions on byte basis. This means that the struct will have to be passed as a "chunk of bytes". Your particular code appears to be the receiver: it has a chunk of raw bytes and states that the data in those bytes corresponds to a struct.

Formally & theoretically, the C standard does not define what happens when you cast between pointers to different data types. In theory, anything can happen if you do. But in practice/the real world, such casts are well-defined as long as there some sort of guarantee about the structure of the data.

Here is where you can get problems. Many computers have alignment requirements, meaning that the compiler is free to insert so-called padding bytes anywhere inside your struct/union. These padding bytes may not necessarily be the same between two compilations, and they may certainly not be the same between two different systems.

So you have to either ensure that both the sender and the receiver have no padding enabled, or that they have the same padding. Otherwise you cannot use structs/unions, they will cause the program to crash and burn.

The quick & dirty way to ensure that struct padding isn't enabled, is to use a compiler option such as the non-standard `#pragma pack 1`, which is commonly supported by many compilers.

The professional, portable way is to add a compile-time assert to check that the size of the struct is indeed as intended. With C11, it would look like

```
static_assert(sizeof(struct icmphdr) == 
                (sizeof(uint8_t) + 
                 sizeof(uint8_t) + ... /* all individual members' types */ ), 
              "Error: padding detected");
```

If the compiler doesn't support `static_assert`, there are several ways to achieve something similar with various macros, or even a runtime `assert()`.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty bad. Don't ever make a char buffer and cast it to a struct, because the alignment will be wrong (ie, the char buffer is going to have some random starting address because strings can start anywhere, but ints need/should have addresses multiples of four on most architectures).

The solution is not to do nasty casts like that. Make a proper union that will have the alignment of the most restrictive of its members, or use a special element to force the alignment you need if you have to (see the definition of sockaddr_storage in your /usr/include/sys/socket.h or similar).

#### Illustration

You create a buffer on the stack and read some data into it:

```
char buf[1024]; int nread = read(fd, &buf, sizeof(buf));
```

Now you pretend the buffer was the struct:

```
CHECK(nread >= sizeof(struct icmphdr));
struct icmphdr* hdr = (struct icmphdr*)buf;
hdr->u.gateway; // probable SIGSEGV on eg Itanium!
```

By reinterpreting the buffer as a struct, we bypassed the compiler's checks. If we're unlucky, `&hdr->u.gateway` won't be a multiple of four, and accessing it as an integer will barf on some platforms.

#### Illustration of solution

```
strut iphdr hdr; int nread = read(fd, &hdr, sizeof(hdr));
CHECK(nread == sizeof(hdr));
hdr.u.gateway; // OK
```

Let the compiler help you. Don't do grotty casts. When you make a buffer, tell the compiler what you're going to use the buffer for so it can put it in the correct place in memory for you.

Comment: Formally, the cast will not give well-defined behavior. But in practice, this cast may make perfect sense in some situations. Suppose you have a data protocol or a file, where you get the whole input byte by byte. This of course assumes that the byte array was created from identical structs, as in the code that "decodes" the byte array: either with no padding or with identical struct padding. This is why using a struct/union for such byte-by-byte purposes, is a bad idea.

Comment: Casting a char buf to a uint32_t never makes sense. If you have a data protocol or file where the binary data matches the layout of a struct, you can't just dumbly cast the buffer to the struct and violate alignment requirements. Just let the compiler help you: tell it the memory is for a struct, it'll work out the allocation of it for you, and then cast that to a char* to fill with data from the file/network.